# About discrete probabilities (Expected values)

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Is my solution correct?

Suppose two player (A and B) each one with 200,00 dollars toss a coin not balanced in a such way that the probability of head is $p$.
Suppose yet that if the result obtained is head then the player A receives 100,00 from the B. And if the result is tail the player A gives 100,00 to the B.
Suppose yet that the game ends when one of then amass 400,00.
Let $N$ the number os toss. Evaluate the expected value of tosses.

Well, My solution was:

The unique way of the game ends is one of the players get his payoff twice in a row.

Then the possible values for this random variable is $k = 2,3,\ldots$.

So
$$P(k=2) = p^2 + (1-p)^2$$
$$P(k=3) = (1-p)p^2 + p(1-p)^2$$
$$P(k=4) = p(1-p)p^2 + (1-p)p(1-p)^2 = (1-p)p^3 + p(1-p)^3$$

Then

$$P(X = k) = 2(p^2 + (1-p)^2) + \sum_{k=3}^{\infty} k[(1-p)p^{k-1} + p(1-p)^{k-1}]$$

Is this right?

Comment: You are not taking into account that the game ends when one player has all the money.  These problems need to be done by backwards induction.

Comment: If you're familiar with Markov Chains, you could model this as a Markov Chain of Player A's wealth, with 0 and 400.00 as absorbing states on the state space {0, 100, 200, 300, 400}, and compute the expected time that way.

Comment: @lulu: He is. Each term alternates between $p$ and $1-p$ before ending in the same result twice.

Comment: In fact I am, thanks @joriki but I made something wrong.  For example, in $k = 3$ once we lost one time, $(1-p)$ we have to win 3 times. So must have to be $p^3$. I think then that the correct formula is: $$P(X = k ) = 2(p^2 + (1-p)^2) + \sum_{k=3}^{\infty}k[(1-p)p^k + p(1-p)^k] $$

Comment: Understood, and something along these lines ought to work. But, I think it is hard to proceed this way...it seems you are trying to enumerate the possible paths and, as you noticed, there are lots of them.  I've written up the induction method.  Hope it is easier!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I meant by backwards induction (Markov chain method is equivalent):

There are only 5 possible states of the world which we will measure by A's wealth in hundreds of thousands of dollars.  Thus we will label the states {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}. We begin in state {2}.  If S is a state let E(S) be the expected number of tosses from state S.  The answer we want is E(2).  We note that E(0) = 0 = E(4). We have three unknowns (E(1), E(2), and E(3)) so we seek three equations connecting them.

Now, say you are in state {3}.  You toss the coin.  With probability p you move to state {4} and with probability (1-p) you move to state {2}.  It follows that $$E(3) = 1 + pE(4) + (1-p)E(2) = 1 + (1-p)E(2)$$.
Similarly $$E(2) = 1 + pE(3) + (1-p)E(1)$$ and
$$E(1) = 1 + pE(2)$$
Thus we have our three equations.  We only really care about E(2) so let's eliminate everything else.  Substituting the expression for E(1) into the middle equation we get, after some algebra,
$$E(2)(1-p+p^2) = 2 - p + pE(3)$$
But the first equation gives us a simple expression for pE(3) in terms of E(2).
Combining everything (and working through the algebra) we arrive at the final answer:  $$E(2) = \frac{2}{1-2p+2p^2}$$
As a sanity check, note that if p = 1 this gives 2, which makes sense (A inevitably wins after 2 tosses).  Similarly p = 0 also gives 2 (and A inevitably loses after 2 tosses).

Answer (score 1):

Your basic approach is sound, but you're making an incorrect generalization in the sum, as you can see if you work out $P(k=5)$. (Also you're writing $P(X=k)$ where it seems you mean the expectation value.)

Anyway, this is a rather cumbersome way to calculate the expected number of tosses. Two successive tosses have outcome "A wins" with probability $p^2$, "B wins" with probability $(p-1)^2$ and "back to square one" with probability $2p(1-p)$. Thus the expected number of tosses satisfies the equation

$$\left<n\right>=2+2p(1-p)\left<n\right>\;,$$

with solution $\left<n\right>=2\,/\left(1-2p+2p^2\right)$.

Comment: Good!  This is cleaner than my method (which appears below).

Answer (score 0):

I think I made a correct solution.
In fact $X$ just take even values.

So, $k = 2,4,6,8,\ldots$.

Then:

$$P(k = 2) = p^2 + (1-p)^2$$
$$P(k = 4) = p(1-p)p^2 + (1-p)p(1-p)^2 = p^3(1-p) + p(1-p)^3$$
$$P(k = 6) = p(1-p)p(1-p)p^2 + (1-p)p(1-p)p(1-p)^2 = p^4(1-p)^2 + (1-p)^4p^2$$
$$EX = \sum_{k \in even}^{n+l = k}k[p^l(1-p)^n + (1-p)^np^l]$$

Comment: No. This is another incorrect generalization, which in this case doesn't in fact generalize the examples you calculated -- it yields two more terms for the $k=6$ probability. The correct generalization only has two terms for every $k$. Also, I wouldn't call this a solution; it's a complicated sum, and the other answers have shown that there's a simple result; so you'd also have to say how your sum can be simplified to that result.

Comment: You did not understand my notation. i know what I mad was correct. A solution not need to be clear to you if its right.

Comment: Your last sentence is certainly true. I see no way of interpreting your notation so as to make it right, but as long as you know you're right, I guess that's what matters...